# .NET 2.0 Client fails to deserialize valid Apache-SOAP web service XML, shows null for all properties

Tags: .net, xml, soap, serialization

A coworker has made a Java web service running on the Apache-SOAP runtime on a Tomcat 6 server, but only tested it using Eclipse's built-in tool and SoapUI. The output of this service is an array of objects which are each composes of five string fields. I need to write a .NET client to consume this service, and I used Visual Studio 2005 to import the WSDL as a web reference. The method executes successfully, and the array is populated with the correct number of objects, but each object's fields are shown as null.

I've used Fiddler to verify that the XML returned to the client is correct, but the .NET client class doesn't seem to be able to deserialize it. Any thoughts?

More data:
 - WSDL is defined as document/literal
 - The return XML doesn't contain "multiref" sections for which I've seen recommendations to write a custom soap attribute
 - The return XML seems to define a new but identical namespace for each object in the return. Could the client merely not understand the different namespace names, even if each resolves to the same type (specified in the WSDL)?
 - The request XML seems to specify UTF-16 instead of UTF-8. Changing this alone doesn't seem to help.
 - Using a third-party tool (.NET WebService Studio) returns a valid response for other methods on the service but the exception "System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1." for the method I'm working on. Is this a separate problem? (I've read it can be caused by Transport-Encoding: chunked)

I'm hoping this is something simple so that I don't have to clean the (long) WSDL of incriminating evidence before posting it here. In the meantime, here's the request and response XML.

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <soap:Body>
        <getPrinterList xmlns="http://service.project.team.dept.company.com" />
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <getPrinterListResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/com.company.team.dept.project.service.projectService">
         <ns1:getPrinterListReturn xmlns:ns1="http://service.project.dept.team.company.com">
            <ns1:printerType>type1</ns1:printerType>
            <ns1:queueName>queue1</ns1:queueName>
            <ns1:description>desc1</ns1:description>
            <ns1:hostName>host1</ns1:hostName>
            <ns1:hostPort>port1</ns1:hostPort>
         </ns1:getPrinterListReturn>
         <ns2:getPrinterListReturn xmlns:ns2="http://service.project.dept.team.company.com">
            <ns2:printerType>type2</ns2:printerType>
            <ns2:queueName>queue2</ns2:queueName>
            <ns2:description>desc2</ns2:description>
            <ns2:hostName>host2</ns2:hostName>
            <ns2:hostPort>port2</ns2:hostPort>
         </ns2:getPrinterListReturn>
         <ns3:getPrinterListReturn xmlns:ns3="http://service.project.dept.team.company.com">
            <ns3:printerType>type3</ns3:printerType>
            <ns3:queueName>queue3</ns3:queueName>
            <ns3:description>desc3</ns3:description>
            <ns3:hostName>host3</ns3:hostName>
            <ns3:hostPort>port3</ns3:hostPort>
         </ns3:getPrinterListReturn>
         <ns4:getPrinterListReturn xmlns:ns4="http://service.project.dept.team.company.com">
            <ns4:printerType>type4</ns4:printerType>
            <ns4:queueName>queue4</ns4:queueName>
            <ns4:description>desc4</ns4:description>
            <ns4:hostName>host4</ns4:hostName>
            <ns4:hostPort>port4</ns4:hostPort>
         </ns4:getPrinterListReturn>
         <ns5:getPrinterListReturn xmlns:ns5="http://service.project.dept.team.company.com">
            <ns5:printerType>type5</ns5:printerType>
            <ns5:queueName>queue5</ns5:queueName>
            <ns5:description>desc5</ns5:description>
            <ns5:hostName>host5</ns5:hostName>
            <ns5:hostPort>port5</ns5:hostPort>
         </ns5:getPrinterListReturn>
      </getPrinterListResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Again, the response is properly brought into the app and cast as an array of the right type and length, but each of the text items in them ("type1", "port1", etc) are being lost. My sincere apologies if anonymizing the XML above has introduced errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a weirdness when connecting a .Net client to Apache Axis in Tomcat before. Did you point your webreference at the *.wsdl file?  Try pointing your webreference at the wsdl definition that Axis prints out. Go to /axis/index.jsp > List > pick the service and click WSDL. Use that URL for your webreference object

It made a big difference to the generated web reference code and also solved encoding issues (RPC versus literal) etc on the XML data

Comment: The WSDL I imported as a web reference was the one supplied by accessing http://host/pathToService?wsdl -- is the service supplied by the service itself any different than the manager application?

Comment: try changing from literal to rpc, redeploy  the servce then redefine the webreference to pick up the change